# Publish Robot Framework test results option is not available after successful installation of Robot Framework plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, robotframework

I've successfully installed Robot Framework plugin in Jenkins. I restarted the server. While configuring my project, Publish Robot Framework test results should be visible in Post-build Actions menu. But this is not the case. There is no such option exists to publish robot framework test results. Am I missing something here?

Comment: also it require freestyle project type and not implemented in a pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins assume that you have installed **suggested plugins** , before you go for Robot framework plugin .

The definition of **suggested plugins** is not much clear and very confusing.

I had resolved this issue by installing Subversion.

**Steps**

1) go to Managed Jenkins >Managed plugins >Available

2) Search Subversion

3) Install Subversion

[image]

This should be able to resolve your issue.

In case of any issue , you can refer this blog [How to configure jenkins with robotframework](http://learningbysimpleway.blogspot.com/2018/08/configuring-jenkins-with-robot-framework.html), i have included all the steps with screenshots.