# 'Publish robot framework test results' not shown in Post-build after successful robot framework plugin installation in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, robotframework

I have installed robot framework plugin for jenkins both through UI and manually to check this. When I tried manually, I had downloaded all the dependant plugins and restarted too. However, I am not getting 'Publish robot framework results' option in post-build step. Please find the list of plugins installed attached [image: here]

I have also tried the solution at [Publish Robot Framework test results option is not available after successful installation of Robot Framework plugin in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606070/publish-robot-framework-test-results-option-is-not-available-after-successful-in) .It wasn't working as well.

Jenkins : 2.138.3
Robot: 1.6.5

Is there a version mismatch perhaps?
Also, I am unable to see any other project options other than Free style when I am creating a new job.

Can someone help me out so that I can see the robot options in jenkins?

Comment: Did you [Skip the "install suggested plugins"](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42167?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20component%20%3D%20robot-plugin) step in the initial installation and performed a manual installation of the suggested plugins?

Comment: No. First, I installed robot from the UI. All the necessory plugins were being installed from what I could see in the screen. I restarted. Couldnt get the robot option. Next I uninstalled the above plugin, noted down which all plugins were installed earlier, installed them manually by pasting in plugins folder. Didnt work either. Jenkins installation was done much before.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a lot of research, I found something that worked for me. I had downloaded the plugin through UI which showed that all the plugins required for the robot plugin were installed(like Junit) in the success section. To doublecheck I went to https://plugins.jenkins.io/robot.

[image]

As you can see the Matrix project and Token Macro were 'Optional'. I went ahead and downloaded them(even if they were mentioned optional) and viola, it Worked! So everybody reading this please make sure that all the plugins mentioned in the plugin site for jenkins are downloaded. Jenkins didnt download them for me automatically when Robot was installed.

JUnit v.1.9 (required)
Matrix Project v.1.4.1 (optional)
Token Macro v.1.5.1 (optional)
bouncycastle API v.2.16.0 (implied)
Command Agent Launcher v.1.0 (implied) 
JDK Tool v.1.0 (implied)